# From this cockpit picture I cannot identify this aircraft. Any ideas?

Tags: aircraft-identification, space-shuttle

It seems a kind of hybrid for testing. The overhead panel looks similar to BAe 146, Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

That is the cockpit of the **[Shuttle Training Aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Training_Aircraft)**, a modified Grumman Gulfstream II. Here is higher resolution picture:

[image: Shuttle Training Aircraft]
<sup>([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Shuttle_Landing_Simulator_cockpit.jpg))</sup>

> The STA is a "highly modified Gulfstream-2 aircraft," Nickel said. The plane’s cockpit has been adapted to closely resemble a Shuttle's flight deck; the left-hand seat features the same hand controls that a Shuttle commander uses during a mission. Several passenger seats in the back of the aircraft have been replaced by a bank of Shuttle-simulating computers.

<sup>([NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/vision/space/preparingtravel/rtf_week5_sta.html))</sup>

They could simulate the glide of the Space Shuttle by flying with the main gear lowered and reverse thrust in flight:

> In order to match the descent rate and drag profile of the real Shuttle, at 37,000 feet (11,300 m), the main landing gear was lowered (the nose gear stayed retracted due to wind load constraints) and engine thrust was reversed. Flaps could be deflected upwards to decrease lift as well as downwards to increase lift.

<sup>([Texas Air and Space Museum](http://www.texasairandspacemuseum.org/nasa-shuttle-training-aircraft.html))</sup>

Comment: `They could simulate the glide of the Space Shuttle by flying with the main gear lowered and reverse thrust in flight` I think this is by far the best description of the shuttle's flight dynamics I've ever heard.  I'm given to understand that there's nothing quite like falling out of the sky in an oil tanker with nothing but two penguin wings and luck to stop you from burying into the dirt...

Comment: It may have been better than being shot round the earth in a tin can on top of a ballistic missile.

Comment: `Flaps could be deflected upwards to decrease lift as well as downwards to increase lift.` Am I mistaken in thinking that flaps don't usually deflect upwards?

Comment: You are not mistaken. Note the phrase "highly modified."

Comment: @zymhan: Depends on context. As John mentioned, this was a special aircraft. Personally, as a glider pilot, "negative flaps" are an extremely common thing.

Comment: There's something fascinating about the white handwritten labelling above the displays.  All the costs, and some dude with a white-out marker and a steady hand is still a critical component.

Comment: @J... I've heard the landing described as trying to land a brick. With a glide angle around and upwards of 20 degrees, it doesn't really look and feel like gliding at all.

Comment: @Mast Yes, I think at 20 degrees it qualifies more as a *fallslope* than a *glideslope*